# Inkcanvas(or an control) in a scrollview margin

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, margin, scrollviewer

So what I'm trying to do, is get the Margin(left, right, what have you) of a child of a ScrollViewer. Every control I've tried always returns a 0 for all.

What I'm trying to do is render an InkCanvas to a bitmap, but I keep ending up with black borders due to not knowing the position of the canvas.

Any ideas on how to solve my issue would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that it isn't possible.